# Start Date set in DAG is evaluating to a day earlier

Tags: airflow

In my DAG I am setting the `start_date` as `2023-09-26` and then when writing a test case, it is coming up as `2023-09-25` and hence failing the test case. I understand that this has something to do with the timezone settings and I am on UK time.

How can I solve this ?

In the DAG:

```py
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow"
    , "depends_on_past": True
    , "retries": 0
    , "start_date": datetime(2023, 9, 26, tzinfo=local_time_zone)
    , "email": [Variable.get("MY_JOB_FAILURE_DL")]
    , "email_on_failure": True
    , "trigger_rule": "all_success"
    , 'on_failure_callback': task_failure_callback
}
```

My test Case:

```py
def details_task_sensor(dag, task_name, start_date, dag_id, task_id):
    task = dag.get_task(task_name)
    
    print("Datetime:" + str(task.start_date)[:10])

    assert (str(task.start_date)[:10] == start_date
            and task.depends_on_past == True
            and task.retries == 0
            and task.external_dag_id == dag_id
            and task.external_task_id == task_id
            and task.allowed_states == ["success"]
            and task.check_existence == True
            and task.mode == "reschedule")
```

I checked using a print statement that the date is coming here as "2023-09-**25**". Happy to provide more info if required.

Thanks

Comment: `default_args` applies to each operator. If you want to define the `start_date` of your DAG you should pass it directly to the DAG params

Comment: sorry I am new to Airflow. But thats how we define the start date for other DAGs as well. However, in those cases the start_date doesn't differ. ALso, can u pls elaborate on passing directly to DAG param please?. Why the test cases are expecting 2023-09-25 when I have defined it as 2023-09-26 ?

Comment: You can find here how to declare a DAG: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#declaring-a-dag

I am not sure about the wrong date, but Airflow dates conception can be confusing.